# How do I loop over json data

Tags: laravel

I am using FlutterWave as my payment gateway, I want to loop through a transaction whenever a customer finish making payment and check for the chargeamount which the user paid. the return data is in json format. Here is my code.

```
  public function callback(Request  $request)
  {
    $resp = $request->resp;
    $body = json_decode($resp, true);
    $txRef = $body['data']['data']['txRef'];
    $data = Rave::verifyTransaction($txRef);

    dd($data);

    return redirect()->route('success');   

  }
```

[image]

I want to loop and check for the chargedamount but I couldn't. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please can you show the code you tried to use to loop through the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are dumping an object. I don't think you need a loop to access the data you need. According to your image dump, to access the `chargedamount` attribute:

```
dd($data->data->chargedamount);
```

The `data` name here repeats, perhaps `$payload` in this case, its a better name.

```
public function callback(Request  $request)
{
    $resp = $request->resp;
    $body = json_decode($resp, true);
    $txRef = $body['data']['data']['txRef'];
    $payload = Rave::verifyTransaction($txRef);

    dd($payload->data->chargedamount);

    return redirect()->route('success');
}
```

Some clean up:

```
public function callback(Request  $request)
{
    $json = json_decode($request->resp);
    
    $payload = Rave::verifyTransaction($json->data->data->txRef);

    dd($payload->data->chargedamount);

    return redirect()->route('success');
}
```

Again that `data->data` repeating stuff, but in this case, nothing we can do, its in the API.